# Ruby execute shell command and get array

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I'm getting a string of few lines from the shell. Is it possible to get an `Array` with each line being its element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, depending on the output you could just split it. For example:

```
lines = `ls`.split
```

This solution is independent of the method you're using to execute the program. As long as you get the complete string you can `split` it.

Answer (score 6):

The original question was splitting on lines, and the `split` function, by default, splits on white space. While that may be sufficient, you may want to pass in a regular expression, as in:

```
`ls -l`.split(/$/)
```

Which returns each line in a separate element in the array. However, it doesn't get rid of the initial carriage return or line feed. For that, you will want to use the `map` function to iterate over the array and apply `strip` to each, as in:

```
`ls -l`.split(/$/).map(&:strip)
```

Comment: Your method is not as good as just using "split". I test with `sudo ifquery --list | grep -v lo`. Yours return ["eth0", "eth1", ""], the last one is annoying.

Comment: but split doesn't work if you have '\n' in your output (as part of the name for example)